# Can I convert HTML to PDF without out converting it to canvas?

Tags: javascript, angular, jspdf

I am using `htmlToCanvas` and `jspdf` in my Angular application. I am successfully converting the HTML to JPEG image then it's getting converted to PDF via jsPdf. But while page break I am facing issue while breaking page.[image: pagebreak]. Here image break is happening.

So, I want to convert HTML page to PDF without converting to canvas. Is there any possible way?

Comment: you can use ngx-print, i find it very easy to customize.

Comment: Or you can use pure window.open with custom css. It will help you easily on Firefox

Answer (score 1):

if u are using jsPDF

```
 doc.addPage({
  format: 'A4',
  orientation: 'landscape'
});
```

add this in your code wheere you want to break a page